# Incorrect Google Profile Results

Tags: google

Where do Google gets the info they display along with your profile in their "Profile Results" that is shown once you hit search for a particular person? When Google shows incorrect info, there's a feedback option at the bottom and it gives you an option to report a problem on which info is wrong. However, this is a tedious task since I've already done this before and they have corrected it but then when I search again after a couple of months, wrong info is shown again. So maybe I need to correct or do something on the process of putting those info into the profile... Not sure where Google gets all these info.. Help?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about [Google Profiles](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=profiles)? (This service now redirects to Google+ - not seeing anywhere that information is automatically added)

Comment: You'd probably need to ask (and provide the details) in the Google+ help forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-plus-discuss

Answer (score 1):

Google allows 'authors' and 'publishers' to link their content to their Google Plus page via the rel attribute of links. It can be an actual "< a href..." link or it can be a non-visible "< link..." element.

Out of privacy concerns, I use the rel=publisher attribute more often than rel=author but for either you have to set up a Google profile and basically opt-in to surveillance...on the plus side, doing so will probably straighten out their search results—well, maybe.

Big Brother says hi.